# Observations (aka realizations) of conditional expectations

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P}) \to (E,\mathcal{E})$ and $Y:(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P}) \to (F,\mathcal{F})$ be random variables.

We suppose $Y$ is **discrete** (i.e $F$ is a countable space) and $X$ is real-valued ($E\subset\mathbb{R}$). Under this setting, the conditional expectation of $X$ knowing $\{Y=y\}$, where $y\in F$ is such that $\mathbb{P}(Y=y)>0$, is defined by :
$$\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]=\dfrac{\mathbb{E}[X1_{\{Y=y\}}]}{\mathbb{P}(Y=y)}$$

The conditional expectation of $X$ with respect to $Y$, denoted $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$, is then defined as $$\mathbb{E}[X|Y]=\varphi \circ Y$$
where $\varphi : F\to\mathbb{R}\text{, } y \mapsto \mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]\text{ if }\mathbb{P}(Y=y)>0\text{, 0 otherwise}$

It is thus obvious that for all $\omega \in \Omega$, $Y(\omega)=y \Longrightarrow \mathbb{E}[X|Y](\omega)=\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]$.

Can we say the same in the more general setting where $X$ and $Y$ are real-valued random variables and $X$ is either positive or $L^1$ ? **In this setting, the definition of $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ is not given by an explicit formula, it is rather defined as the unique random variable verifying for all bounded measurable function $g:F\to\mathbb{R}$  : $\mathbb{E}[Xg(Y)]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y]g(Y)]$**

Comment: Note that the conditional expectation is usually defined as a random variable, so it would be more appropriate to say that the function $y \mapsto \mathbb E[X|Y=y]$ from $(F,\mathcal F) \to (\mathbb R, \mathcal B_{\mathbb R})$ is measurable and $\mathbb E[X|Y] : (\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathbb P) \to (F,\mathcal F) \to (\mathbb R, \mathcal B_{\mathbb R})$ is defined as their composition.

Comment: In the general setting, $E(X\mid Y)$ is not defined as a specific random variable but as a class of random variables, each equal to each other up to some null set, thus the value $E(X\mid Y)(\omega)$ at any specific $\omega$ has no meaning (except if $P(\{\omega\})\ne0$). For example, for every event $A$ such that $P(A)=1$, $Y$ and $Y\mathbf 1_A$ are two perfectly legitimate versions of $E(Y\mid Y)$ but $(Y\mathbf 1_A)(\omega)$ and $Y(\omega)$ differ if $\omega$ is in $\Omega\setminus A$. This is why one should actually always write $$E(X\mid Y)=Z\ \text{almost surely.}$$

Comment: Does the implication hold for $\omega$'s outside a negligible set in which $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ can take arbitrary values ?

Comment: @Patrick Da Silva : I modified my post according to your remark

Comment: @Did : I chose one specific version of $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$, the one that value at 0 when $\mathbb{P}(Y=Y(\omega))=0$

Comment: @Did : hahaha... my probability course is so long ago!

Comment: @dada So, if $P(Y=y)=0$ for every $y$ (that is, for every continuous random variable $Y$), you suggest to "choose" the "specific version" $E(X\mid Y)$ which is identically equal to $0$, that is, to define $E(X\mid Y)=0$ whatever $X$ is? Sorry but this does not make any sense.

Comment: IOW, the definition $\varphi : F\to\mathbb{R}\text{, } y \mapsto \mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]\text{ if }\mathbb{P}(Y=y)>0\text{, 0 otherwise}$, leads to chaos.

Comment: I explicitly mentioned that the definition with $\varphi$ is for **discrete** random variables $Y$

Comment: @dada So for any particular representative, call it $Z$, of  $E[X|Y]$, there is a null set $N_Z$ such that if $\omega \not \in N_Z$ and $Y(\omega)=y$ then $E[X|Y](\omega)=E[X|Y=y]$. (This is assuming the latter even really makes sense.) However, by changing the representative $Z$, you can typically make this equality fail at any particular $\omega$, even though it never fails at more than a null set at once. (Of course it can never fail at an $\omega$ with positive probability.)

Comment: Why $\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]$ doesn't make sense ? It's the expectation of $X$ under the new probability measure induced by the event $\{Y=y\}$ : $\mathbb{E}[X1_{\{Y=y\}}]$

Comment: This is the heart of the problem: how to define this new probability measure when $P(Y=y)=0$? (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: "I explicitly mentioned that the definition with φ is for discrete random variables Y" You lost me: are you not asking "Can we say the same" in the general case, that is, when Y is **not** discrete?

Comment: While true that the conditional expectation is a collection of random variables, they are not all the same. Under some commonly occurring circumstances, one of these random variables stands out: it is the limit $\lim_{\Delta y\downarrow0} E(X|Y\in(y-\Delta y, y+\Delta y))$ of the discrete conditional expectations $E(X|Y\in(y-\Delta y, y+\Delta y))$. I've proven this in another post w.r.t. the conditional probability $P(A|Y=y)$, but the result can be readily extended to the case of conditional expectation.

Comment: @Did : by definition of the conditional probability wrt to an event, we choose an event with strictly positive probability. So $y$ is chosen such that $P(Y=y)>0$ when we want to define a new measure of probability conditionally to $\{Y=y\}$. The definition of $\varphi$ distinguishes between such $y$'s and the other $y$'s

Comment: @Did : When $Y$ is not discrete, the definition of the conditional expectation is not the same as the one I gave at the beginning of my post. See at the end of the post. I detailed that definition to show that $\mathbb{E}[X|Y](\omega)=\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]$ when $Y(\omega)=y$

Comment: "I detailed that definition to show that..." Yeah, and I already destroyed this "detailed" part. It does not hold, in two senses: the proof does not work and the result itself does not hold.

Comment: @Did : this can't be when $Y$ is discrete, because otherwise, if you sum over all $y$'s you'll end up with 0, while the total mass of probability is 1

Comment: Again: are you not trying to solve cases not purely discrete? Or what is the question about? At the moment, you have done much in this thread to convince people that you are in fact completely lost with the maths involved, so let me suggest to make a pause and to come back with some nonambiguous question and/or statements and/or whatever. Done deal?

Comment: I'm trying to see if the following is true when $X$ and $Y$ are real-valued random variables : $E[X|Y](\omega)=E[X|Y=Y(\omega)]$

Comment: And the answer to that is an unequivocal "No" (except when $Y$ is discrete), as explained **in my very first comment**. Please stop wasting everybody's time because you desperately want the answer to be "Yes".

Comment: Thank you for being so nice ;)

Comment: You are welcome. Please explain what *this whole thread* is about, starting after my first comment. Thanks in advance.